# TypeScript: noop => noop

Tags: typescript, no-op

I've seen the syntax `noop => noop` [here](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/dae9929a116d59f19d0c78c0c8659a833ae414eb/docs/Troubleshooting.md#it-doesnt-work-with-other-store-enhancers). I was rather expecting something like `() => noop` to be valid. What does `noop => noop` stand for and when should one use this?

Comment: `noop` is short for "no operation". It's a function whose output is its input _without any operation applied_. That's it. Though I'll admit, it's more typical to name the _function_ `noop` than it is to name its input and output `noop`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`noop => noop` defines a function that takes a parameter named `noop` and returns that paremeter. It's the [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function).

There's nothing magical about the name `noop`; `x => x` would be equivalent.  `() => noop` is not a valid function because `noop` wouldn't refer to anything.